# fomating using stream in C++ writing to files

Tags: c++

I am writing to a file in C++ using streams by using following code and output is shown following the code. Here I want to format like second column is of size 10 and values should be right aligned in same way for third column as well.

```
for (unsigned int dvIdx = 0; dvIdx <  3; dvIdx++)
{
    dataFile << myData.TimeChanged().Format().c_str() << "  " <<  myData.GetValue() 
        << "  " <<  myData.GetQuality() << std::endl; 
}


2012-06-25 12:01:04.000  1  1083507713
2012-06-25 12:01:20.000  3  1029
2012-06-25 12:01:36.000  -empty-  2157642752
```

Expected output is

```
2012-06-25 12:01:04.000        1  1083507713
2012-06-25 12:01:20.000        3        1029
2012-06-25 12:01:36.000  -empty-  2157642752
```

How can I change above code to get expected output. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: It would be good to know how myData.GetValue() is defined. Without this information, answering this question is all guesswork.

Comment: @venkysmarty  why don't you google and experiment a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must look for [`<iomanip>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/), `setw` and `setiosflags`

```
dataFile << myData.TimeChanged().Format() << "  "
         << std::setw(10) << std::setiosflags(std::ios::right)
         << myData.GetValue() 
         << std::setw(10) << std::setiosflags(std::ios::right)
         << "  " <<  myData.GetQuality() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [**setw**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bbhbaew%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) format specifier:

```
for (unsigned int dvIdx = 0; dvIdx <  3; dvIdx++)
{
    dataFile << myData.TimeChanged().Format().c_str() << "  " 
        << setw(10) <<  myData.GetValue() << "  "
        << setw(20) <<  myData.GetQuality() << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: And don't forget that you need to include `<iomanip>` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [I/O manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/). Looks to me that `setw(10)` would do the job.